# Input Box Values Disappear on Button Click

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

I am just starting out with JQuery for asp.net core mvc.

I have a section of a page comprising a list of items linked to the main subject. When an 'edit' button is clicked against one of the list items, a hidden section (fieldset) is displayed and populated with the values of that list item. Other inputs on the page are disabled and the user can edit the item. All works fine.

However, when finished editing, the user clicks a 'submit' button (within the previously hidden fieldset) and the idea is to submit the edited data via ajax and, if accepted, to update the list. Ajax, etc. is not (yet) the problem.

When the user clicks the 'submit' button (coded as type="button"), the values in the edited section appear to have been cleared and are returned as spaces or nulls. It only seems to apply to this fieldset, as (disabled) values from the remainder of the document can be retrieved (just for testing purposes).

Can anyone tell me what is going on here and how to preserve these edited values, please?

```
    @**** Drop-down section for editing Admissions ****@
<fieldset id="AdmissionsEditFieldset" class="app-edit-main-fieldset" hidden>
    <legend id="AdmissionsEditLegend" class="app-edit-fieldset-legend">Editing Admission</legend>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="padding-left: 5%; padding-right: 5%">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong><label>Institution:</label></strong>
                <span class="app-label-to-input-sep">
                    <input id="admId" name="aId" type="text" class="form-input app-can-disable" asp-for="Admission.Id" hidden />
                    <select id="admPlace" name="aPlace" type="text" class="app-can-disable" asp-items="Model.PlaceOfDetentionDd" asp-for="Admission.PlaceId"></select>
                </span>
                <strong><label class="app-input-fld-sep">Date Admitted:</label></strong>
                <span class="app-label-to-input-sep">
                    <input id="admDate" name="aDate" type="text" class="form-input app-can-disable" asp-for="Admission.DateAdmitted" style="width: 5%" />
                </span>
                <strong><label class="app-input-fld-sep">Sequence:</label></strong>
                <span class="app-label-to-input-sep app-can-disable">
                    <input id="admSeq" name="aSeq" type="text" class="form-input" asp-for="Admission.Seq" style="width: 5%" />
                </span>
                <span>
                    <button id="admSubmitBtn" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary app-adm-edit-btn" type="button">Submit</button>
                    <button id="admCancelBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger app-button-to-button-sep">Cancel</button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="padding-left: 5%; padding-right: 5%">

        </div>
    </div>
```

And this is the JavaScript/JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 $('.app-adm-edit-btn').click(function (event) {
   //*** Prevent default button actions
   event.preventDefault();
  // btn has format 'editN[N...]'

  var btn = event.target.id;
  var sid = btn.substring(4);

  //*** Un-hide the editing drop-down
  $('#AdmissionsEditFieldset').removeAttr('hidden');

  //*** Copy values from the relevent line in the  table to the editing drop-down
  $('#admId').val($('#ident' + sid).text());
  $('#admPlace').val($('#placeN' + sid).text());
  $('#admDate').val($('#dateAdm' + sid).text());
  $('#admSeq').val($('#seq' + sid).text());

  //*** Set the section legend
  $('#AdmissionsEditLegend').text('Editing an Admission');

  //*** Disable other sections
  DisableFieldsets();  // Works OK - makes no difference if commented out

  //*** Focus the first input box
  $('#admPlace').focus();

 });  // $('.app-adm-edit-btn').click

 /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Admissions Submit button click handler
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
 $('#admSubmitBtn').click(function (event) {
  //*** Prevent default button actions
  event.preventDefault();

  // Just to verify nothing wrong with JSON.stringify
  var id = $('#admId').val();
  var placeId = $('#admPlace').val();
  var seq = $('#admSeq').val();
  var dateAdmitted = $('#admDate').val();
  var court = $('#Court').val();

  // Not integrated, so that I can display the values
  var jsn = JSON.stringify({
   Id: $('#admId').val(),
   PlaceId: $('#admPlace').val(),
   Seq: $('#admSeq').val(),
   DateAdmitted: $('#admDate').val()
  });

  $.ajax({
   url: "api/EditAdmissionApi",
   method: "POST",
   contentType: "application/json",
   data: jsn,
   success: function (data) {
    alert("Ajax Success");  //TODO
   }
  });
  alert(jsn);
  //TODO
 });

  /*------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Admissions Cancel button click handler
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
 $('#admCancelBtn').click(function (event) {
   //*** Prevent default button actions
   event.preventDefault();
 });

 });  // $(document).ready

 /*===========================================================================
   Helper Functions
  ===========================================================================*/
 /*---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  DisableFieldsets Helper function to disable fieldsets while input of linked
  items takes place 
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
   function DisableFieldsets() {
    DoDisableFieldsets('#MainFieldset');
    DoDisableFieldsets('#AdmissionsFieldset');
    DoDisableFieldsets('#ChildrenFieldset');
    DoDisableFieldsets('#SubmitButtonsNonFieldset');
   }

   function DoDisableFieldsets(id) {
    var xId = $(id);
    $('.app-can-disable', xId).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $(xId).addClass('app-disabled-background');
   }
```

Comment: If you comment out `$('#admId').val($('#ident' + sid).text());` does one of the fields stop being cleared?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does and many thanks for the suggestion, mj.

Trying to see why and testing alternatives brought me to the real issue, however. I have to confess that it was one of those stupidities that you can stare at for hours without seeing. Still I will confess, in case it helps anyone else.

I had given the Edit buttons in the list a 'dummy' class name to make selection easier. Then I had inadvertently copied and adapted the button html to be the Submit button following edit, **without deleting the class**. So both the Edit and Submit button handlers seemed to be called, which was causing havoc (I have not yet worked out why this was not just producing the unedited text in the second handler - but life's too short). So a dumb question on my part - sorry for wasting everyone's time.

The construct $('#admId').val($('#ident' + sid).text()); works fine now.